# Not receiving pushwoosh push notification message in the device

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, push-notification

I just installed the pushwoosh for android/phonegap and I am testing it with an android device connected to my laptop.  It seems that the device has been registered successfully but after sending a push notification message, the notification was not displayed on the device.  In the show detail message in pushwoosh, it says "unauthorized", not very sure what the unauthorized here means?  I could see 1 subscriber in pushwoosh and this should have indicated that the notification have reached android galaxy note.

Any advice would be helpful.  The catlog is as below:

05-16 09:49:27.509: I/GCMIntentService(21339): Device registered: regId = APA91bGgV04WDohU3SOorijBG6Qa_Duu6HytWwqemyH0CzsRep2OLe-DgSChzwTcqu_xDrFALY34lmbuiaFeNQptaMQ14NaYfl3syLzEa1Vi3OQQ10rZLSY0EqTPydUrVerK8DNCyxBy
05-16 09:49:27.509: W/DeviceRegistrar(21339): Try To Registered for pushes
05-16 09:49:28.119: W/PushWoosh: NetworkUtils(21339): PushWooshResult: {"status_code":200,"status_message":"OK","response":null}
05-16 09:49:28.119: W/PushWoosh DeviceFeature2_5(21339): Send AppOpen success

Comment: It turned out that my android api was set incorrectly in pushwoosh.  Now it is displaying the message.  However, the message is null.  Look like the user data is null.  Hope someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on the null message.
Looking at my console log I found this:

```
message is: {"message":"test", *other stuff here* }
```

After looking around I found this answer, which solved the problem for me. (and was actually embarrassingly obvious)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16628012

I hope that works for you as well!

Comment: I simply followed the instructions in the pushwoosh web site and did a reinstallation and it works on the galaxy tabs that I have used for testing.  However, my friend just downloaded the app from the google play store but he did not receive any of the notifications.